# Determining a Style Changeover by Machine using PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

So I have a table that has the output of all machines in a department with styles. For example:

```
|Machine| |Style| | QTY|  |Time|   |Date|    etc...
     1       001    100   8:00AM   5/21/19
     2       001    200   8:05AM   5/21/19
     1       001    100   9:00AM   5/21/19     
     1       004    100   10:00AM  5/21/19
     2       001    200   9:05AM   5/21/19
```

I'm looking to see the amount of times a style is changed for a machine. So in this case, for Machine 1 it was one style change and for Machine 2 it was zero.

I've tried adapting some code to no avail; mainly because I'm having trouble understanding the logic and I can't really think of a good index to work with. 
Here is what I got so far:

```
EarliestChange Over Index = 
VAR Temp =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( Table[Index] ),
        FILTER (
            Table,
            [Index] < EARLIER ( [Index] )
                && [Style] <> EARLIER ( [Style])
                && Table[Date] = today()-1
        )
    )
VAR Temp1 =
    CALCULATE (
        MIN ( [Index] ),
        FILTER (
            Table,
            [Index] > EARLIER ( [Index] )
                && [Style] <> EARLIER ( [Style])
                && Table[Date] = today()-1
        )
    )
RETURN
   IF ( [Index] > temp && OR ( [Index] < temp1, ISBLANK ( temp1 ) ), temp + 1, 0 )
```

I tried to restrict it to just one day so that I could evaluate the results so that portion can be dropped. I've tried two different indexes, one was the machine number and the other was the difference in time from today and the min date on the table. In a visual, I've been taking a distinct count of the EarliestChange Over Index and subtracted one since it didn't constitute a "change over."

EDIT:
Issue where multiple styles are logged at the same time causing false change overs.

```
    |Machine| |Style| | QTY|  |Time|   |Date|    etc...
         1       001    100   8:00AM   5/21/19
         1       001    100   9:00AM   5/21/19     
         1       004    100   10:00AM  5/21/19
         1       004    100   10:00AM  5/21/19
         1       004    100   10:00AM  5/21/19
```

In one department a time would never be duplicated. However, in another department (for whatever reason) might log 3 rolls at the same time. This would cause the equation to log 10:00am as 3 change overs. It might be a system glitch why there isn't unique time stamps per roll but this is the case unfortunately.

Comment: Do you need it as a measure or a calculated column?

Comment: If you don't revert to old styles, then you should be able to use a count of distinct styles per machine - 1.

Comment: Unfortunately we run 70 or so machines and there could be any number of change overs per machine per day.

Comment: @RADO It can be either.

Comment: @C.Mayers - so if machine 1 has style 001, then style 004, and then back to style 001, that would be 2 style changes?

Comment: @RADO yes precisely but if it went 001, 001, 004 then it would be 1

Comment: I know it has been a bit @RADO but I'm running into an issue that I can't seem to control. The code is perfect but the problem occurs when time stamps are the same within a machine and a style (which makes sense since it's looking for a distinct timestamp). Not sure if its as system glitch on our end but it seems to happen a lot. How might I be able to get the distinct count of that change over ?

Comment: Can you explain the problem in more details? I don't quite get it. An example would be very helpful.

Comment: So I added the edit but basically. The code determines that if say a changeover is true and three rolls have the same time stamp then it would make sense that it would log those three rolls as three changeovers. I need to display one. As a workaround, I did a distinct count of the time stamps but this doesn't obviously work without that context. More or less I need there to never be more than a "1" for a timestamp even if there are multiple time stamps with the same time. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing it:

First, I modified your data as follows:

[image]

- Added a record for Machine 1 at 11:00AM to capture a situation when a style reverts to the old one;
- Added a column for Date-Time (simply Date + Time), to make life easier;
- Named the table as "Data"

Measure:

```
Style Change Count
=
SUMX (
    Data,
    VAR Current_DateTime = Data[Date-Time]
    VAR Current_Style = Data[Style]
    VAR Previous_DateTime =
        CALCULATE (
            MAX ( Data[Date-Time] ),
            FILTER ( ALLEXCEPT ( Data, Data[Machine] ), Data[Date-Time] < Current_DateTime )
        )
    VAR Previous_Style =
        CALCULATE (
            VALUES ( Data[Style] ),
            FILTER ( ALLEXCEPT ( Data, Data[Machine] ), Data[Date-Time] = Previous_DateTime )
        )
    RETURN
        IF ( Current_Style = Previous_Style || ISBLANK ( Previous_Style ), 0, 1 )
)
```

Result:

[image]

How it works:

- We need to use SUMX to make sure that our subtotals and totals are correct;
- SUMX iterates over Data table and for each record computes "Previous date-time", which is simply the max datetime less than the current datatime, per machine (hence ALLEXCEPT);
- Then, we can calculate Previous Style, which is a style where date-time = previous date-time;
- Finally, we compare current style and previous style. If they are not the same, we add 1;
- In addition, I added a test for the starting condition - first occurrence of a machine, for which previous style does not exist yet. I did not treat such records as "style change". If you want to count initial records as style change, remove ISBLANK() part.

Comment: Bravo! Nice job!

Comment: Very impressive, simple and effective!!